# SQL Server 2005 Query Help

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table and I want to get the row before the last one.
Eg

```
KeyboardID     KeyboardName
1                 "DELL"
2                 "HP"
3                 "Viewsonic"
4                 "Samsung"
```

select max(keyboardid) from keyboard -> will get the Samsung

My Question is how to get the Viewsonic Keyboard...

Comment: This raises a "red flag" in my mind. I would be interested to know the context in which you intend to do this. It's not my intention to sound sarcastic or unhelpful, I just think that it might be useful to attack the problem from a different angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeyboardId DESC) AS rn
  FROM Table
) AS t
WHERE rn = 2;
```

or

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeyboardId DESC) AS rn
   FROM Table)
SELECT *
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 2;
```

or

```
SELECT TOP(1) *
  FROM (
  SELECT TOP(2) * 
      FROM Table
      ORDER BY KeyboardId DESC) AS t
  ORDER BY KeyboardId;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Keyboard
WHERE KeyboardID < (SELECT MAX(KeyboardID) FROM Keyboard)
ORDER BY KeyboardID DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually have this as an interview question.  To get just the id:

```
SELECT MAX(KeyboardID) as SecondPlaceID
FROM Keyboard
WHERE KeyboardID < (SELECT MAX(KeyboardID) FROM Keyboard)
```

or for the full row:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Keyboard
    WHERE KeyboardID = (SELECT MAX(KeyboardID)
                        FROM Keyboard
                        WHERE KeyboardID < 
                              (SELECT MAX(KeyboardID) FROM Keyboard))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @MaxID Int
Select @MaxID = max(KeyboardID) from tblFacts

Select top 1 * from tblFacts where KeyBoardID < @MaxID
Order by @MaxID desc
```

Comment: That would return "DELL"...ORDER BY needs to be DESC